# Bootstrap conflicting with my own css file Flask and Jinja template

Tags: html, css, flask, jinja2, bootstrap-5

I have a problem. I included bootstrap and css file in my template, bootstrap before css, and when i want to implement custom css with id or class nothing changes. However h1 is working fine.

My code for layout.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
  ...
  <head>
    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Bootstrap-picker -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-mSYUmp1HYZDFaVKK//63EcZq4iFWFjxSL+Z3T/aCt4IO9Cejm03q3NKKYN6pFQzY0SBOr8h+eCIAZHPXcpZaNw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <!--Include my own css file-->
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  ...
{% endblock content %}
```

Then my main.css in static folder:

```css
h1 {
  color: #129944;
}
#my-image-main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

And my .html file

```html
<div class="col">
  <img src="{{image}}" class="img-fluid rounded-circle border" id="my-image-main" alt="Profile picture">
</div>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Not relevant. I just needed to delete browser cache :)